# Set background of Swing JTextField

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtextfield, background-color

I have the following the Java code for the window with two text fields: one editable, the other - not. I would like to gray out the non-editable text field. I use `setBackground()` function and it seems to work in the Eclipse design viewer:

[image]

However, when I export it to `jar`, the resulting application looks like this:

[image]

I am using `Eclipse 4.4.1` under `MacOS 10.9.3`.

My code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    JTextField text0;

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Test window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JTextField editableTextField, nonEditableTextField;

        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        editableTextField = new JTextField("Enter text here");
        constraints.gridx=0;
        constraints.gridy=0;
        container.add(editableTextField, constraints);

        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        nonEditableTextField = new JTextField("See result here");
        nonEditableTextField.setBackground(getForeground());
        nonEditableTextField.setEditable(false);
        constraints.gridx=0;
        constraints.gridy=1;
        container.add(nonEditableTextField, constraints);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Why the behavior is different in the viewer and `jar`?
2. How to 'gray out' a text field in `jar`?

Comment: What about setEnabled(false) ?

Comment: @Berger `setEnabled()` has a bit different behavior. It makes the text gray, but not the background, and I would like to have text of standard color on the background, which color matches the color of the app frame background, like on the first image.

Comment: It  could have something to do with the look and feel and or the UI Defaults been installed

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to apply `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel")` at the very beginning of the program: it changed the theme, both in th viewer and `jar`; however, the second text field remained black in `jar`.

Comment: *"gray out the non-editable text field"*  See also [`setEnabled(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled-boolean-) ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that there is actually a difference between `getBackground()` and `getContentPane().getBackground()`. However, neither of them is responsible the actually seen grayish default window background. `getForeground()` also does not code for this color; however, for some reason it is initialized to the coinciding value in the viewer.

Nevertheles, it is possible to override the default background color through `getContentPane().setBackground()` (though its initial value does not match):

```
    ...
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
    ...
    nonEditableTextField.setBackground(container.getBackground());
    ...
```

This generates the desirable effect both in the design viewer and `jar`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set the background color to the foreground color (which is black here), you get everything in the same color.

```
setBackground(getForeground());
```

Try setting some other Color.

Comment: This does not answer neither of my questions. Why does it not become black in the viewer then?

Comment: It does answer question 2, it is up to you to choose a grayish color.

Answer (score 0):

```
setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.inactiveBackground"));
```

Comment: Add some explanation to answer how this help OP instead of just adding one code line.Thanks

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

For your First Question:
As someone said it above `It could have something to do with the look and feel and or the UI Defaults been installed`

As for the Second Question:

1. You can use `UIManager.getColor` OR
2. You can use `Color` class for setting the `gray` color for your `non editable` text field. Just use `Color.LIGHT_GRAY` or `Color.GRAY` or any other constants that you would want to use.

Both methods will work the same in both the Eclipse IDE and the JAR File.

Modification:

```
1) nonEditableTextField.setBackground(UIManager.getColor(Color.lightGray));

2) nonEditableTextField.setBackground(UIManager.getColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
```

OR

```
nonEditableTextField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

However, First method is more preferable than the second one.